# Play 2.0.2 Futures timed out after [5000] milliseconds

Tags: playframework-2.0, akka

What version of Akka Play 2.0.2 is using? It seems that Akka already removed the future timeout in this issue. https://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/1433

Why I am still getting timeout exception?

```
2012-08-02T18:51:59+00:00 app[web.1]: play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [5000] milliseconds]]
2012-08-02T18:51:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:134) [play_2.9.1-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
2012-08-02T18:51:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115) [play_2.9.1-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
2012-08-02T18:51:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:318) [akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
2012-08-02T18:51:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113) [play_2.9.1-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
2012-08-02T18:51:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:626) [akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
2012-08-02T18:51:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:197) [akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
2012-08-02T18:51:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [5000] milliseconds
2012-08-02T18:51:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   at akka.dispatch.DefaultPromise.ready(Future.scala:870) ~[akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
2012-08-02T18:51:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   at akka.dispatch.DefaultPromise.result(Future.scala:874) ~[akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
2012-08-02T18:51:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   at akka.dispatch.Await$.result(Future.scala:74) ~[akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
2012-08-02T18:51:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaPromise.await(Akka.scala:43) ~[play_2.9.1-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
2012-08-02T18:51:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise$class.await(Promise.scala:55) ~[play_2.9.1-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
2012-08-02T18:51:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaPromise.await(Akka.scala:28) ~[play_2.9.1-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, from the 2.0.2 tag, Play uses Akka 2.0.2

You can check [here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.0.2/framework/project/Build.scala#L186).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested in new status() method in Play 2.2, this is how I increase timeout during test.

```
status(resp)(akka.util.Timeout(200000)) must equalTo(OK)
```